# how to transfer media files from windows7 to windows phone

Tags: windows-7

i have lumia 520 and i am trying to copy media files from windows 7 to windows phone, but that wont work, instead the device every time behaves as a mass storage device and the media copied or transferred cannot be played on the phone, but can be transferred to any other OS or pc.

So my question is how to add files to a windows phone from your windows 7 pc so that they can be played in your windows phone

Answer (score 2):

There is an app available for Windows 7 by Microsoft which should solve most of your described problems.
Windows Phone App for Desktop: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/how-to/wp8/windows-phone-app-for-desktop